# How to extract dependencies from a PyPi package without downloading it?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, package-management

I want to get the dependency of a PyPi package remotely without needing to download it completely.

I seem to understand (reading the pip code) that pip when resolving dependencies seems to read the egg once the package has been downloaded.

Is there any other way?

Comment: It'll either be in a `requirements.txt` or in `setup.py`, maybe you could download just a single file from the repo, depending on where it's hosted? (i.e. github as opposed to PyPi) [Related Q](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.python/gclDOiXeN_c)

Comment: why not, but that needs to be specific to each package, if i don't want to do it by hand for "any" package, it won't be so easy...

Comment: You can fetch PyPI package metadata in JSON format at `https://pypi.org/pypi/<package name>/json`, for example https://pypi.org/pypi/tensorflow/json

Comment: @JongbinPark Thanks, it it really useful, you can also view a specific version info at `https://pypi.org/pypi/<package name>/<package version>/json` additionally, for example https://pypi.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools/5.15.4.3.2/json.

Comment: @AlexL Sometimes It is not easy or straightforward to find the dependences from `setup.py`, for example https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/blob/main/setup.py#L88.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just needed to find a way to do this and this is what I came up with (stolen from pip).

```
def dist_metadata(setup_py):
    '''Get the dist object for setup.py file'''

    with open(setup_py) as f:
        d = f.read()

    try:
        # we have to do this with current globals else
        # imports will fail. secure? not really. A
        # problem? not really if your setup.py sources are 
        # trusted
        exec d in globals(), globals()
    except SystemExit:
        pass

    return distutils.core._setup_distribution
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505166/3332282 answers why the exec incantation is subtle and hard to get right.

Comment: Thanks - tricky! But note that you need `import distutils` at the top, and the caller will want to look at `dist_metadata(setup_py).install_requires`, which returns a list of package names. That leaves the question of how to get the `setup.py` without downloading the whole package, as OP requested.

Comment: This does not work as-is with Python3. You need to change  `exec d in globals(), globals()` to `exec(d, globals())` and to get requirements looks at the `dist_metadata(setup_py).get_requires()` method.

Answer (score 13):

As jinghli notes, there isn't currently a reliable way to get the dependency of an arbitrary PyPi package remotely without needing to download it completely. And in fact the dependencies sometimes depend on your environment, so an approach like Brian's of executing setup.py code is needed in the general case.

The way the Python ecosystem handles dependencies started evolving in the 1990's before the problem was well understood. [PEP 508 -- Dependency specification for Python Software Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) sets us on course to improve the situtation, and an "*aspirational*" draft approach in [PEP 426 -- Metadata for Python Software Packages 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/) may improve it more in the future, in conjunction with the reimplementation of PyPI as [Warehouse](https://pypi.org/).

The current situation is described well in the document [Python Dependency Resolution](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x_VrNtXCup75qA3glDd2fQOB2TakldwjKZ6pXaAjAfg/).

PyPI does provide a [json interface](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON?action=show&redirect=PyPiJson) to download metadata for each package. The `info.requires_dist` object contains a list of names of required packages with optional version restrictions etc.  It is often missing, but it is one place to start.

E.g. [Django (json)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/json) indicates:

`{
    "info": {
...
        "requires_dist": [
            "bcrypt; extra == 'bcrypt'", 
            "argon2-cffi (>=16.1.0); extra == 'argon2'", 
            "pytz"
        ], 
...
}`

Comment: The `requires_dist` block doesn't show up for the linked JSON from pypi anymore :(

Comment: Thanks @AshBerlin. I changed the example, since jupyter no longer has a `requires_dist`

Comment: I think it does (again?)? A sample [here](https://pypi.org/pypi/pymc/json). You can just search for `requires_dist`. This answer should be the accepted one, nice explanation @nealmcb!

Answer (score 13):

Use [pipdeptree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipdeptree) to view dependencies of **installed** PyPI packages.

Install:

```
pip install pipdeptree
```

Then run:

```
pipdeptree
```

You'll see something like that:

```
Warning!!! Possible conflicting dependencies found:
* Mako==0.9.1 -> MarkupSafe [required: >=0.9.2, installed: 0.18]
  Jinja2==2.7.2 -> MarkupSafe [installed: 0.18]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lookupy==0.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
argparse==1.2.1
psycopg2==2.5.2
Flask-Script==0.6.6
  - Flask [installed: 0.10.1]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.7, installed: 0.9.4]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.4, installed: 2.7.2]
      - MarkupSafe [installed: 0.18]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.21, installed: 0.23]
alembic==0.6.2
  - SQLAlchemy [required: >=0.7.3, installed: 0.9.1]
  - Mako [installed: 0.9.1]
    - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.9.2, installed: 0.18]
ipython==2.0.0
slugify==0.0.1
redis==2.9.1
```

Comment: How do you make this work with pipenv?

Comment: oh come on @Rockallite, the title said "without downloading it"....

Comment: @user1835157: __technically__ if you already have it installed , you won't need to download it *shrug*

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, pip doesn't have this function. The metadata available for packages on PyPI does not include information about the dependencies.

Normally, you can find the detailed dependency from the README file from project website.

`pip search` can give some information about the package. It can tell you what is it based on.

```
$ pip search flask
Flask     - A microframework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm really surprised! I assumed, based on how Debian/Ubuntu package management works, that this would be a basic piece of data to require from packages in a standard way, so that tools like [pypi-data](https://github.com/nathforge/pypi-data) could show the full dependency tree. Though I dare say it's complicated....

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch PyPI package metadata in JSON format using a URL like: `https://pypi.org/pypi/<package name>/json`.

Example: https://pypi.org/pypi/tensorflow/json

*From a comment on the OP that was the right answer for me.*