# Use exec to execute a file inside a function with globals()

Tags: python, execfile

I need to execute a file inside a python shell.

I can

```
exec(open('Test.py').read())
```

But I need to call it from inside a function.

"Test.py" will set variable C=10

So,

```
#x.py
def load(file):
    exec(open(file).read(),globals())

>>> import x
>>> x.load('Test.py')
>>> C
>>> NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

I have passed in the globals, but I still cant access the varibales from exec.
References:

[In Python, why doesn't an import in an exec in a function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505047/in-python-why-doesnt-an-import-in-an-exec-in-a-function-work)

[How to execute a file within the python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter)

Comment: `execfile("filepath")`

Comment: Because you I cannot reproduce this...

Comment: It would be helpful to mention Python3.6. 'execfile' does not work

Answer (score 0):

use `import` instead

```
from Test import C
print C
```

**EDIT:**

If Test.py is in a different directory, you have to modify the `sys.path`

```
import sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, "path_to_directory")

from Test import C
print C
```

Comment: What do I do if my Test is located in a different directory? (apart from path append)

Answer (score 0):

So here is one way to do it

```
#x.py
def load(file):
    exec(open(file).read())
    return locals()

>>> import x
>>> var = x.load('Test.py')
>>> locals().update(var)
>>> C
>>> 10
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there a way to not have any variable associated "var". Directly access C

Comment: How would you access if x is in a different directory?

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of x.py ? Wasn't it supposed to call files from different directory?

Comment: I wanted a single instruction which can do it in the shell. possible?