Typing List not defined when running code with exec from a function
Can somebody help me understand why the following code fails?
def foo(code):
    exec(code)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    code = R"""
from typing import List
class Test:
    def __init__(a: List):
        pass
    """
    foo(code)
    # exec(code)  # this works

I'm using Python 3.9.19 on MacOS.
Also, the following changes make the example work:

Replacing List with list
running exec(code) before foo
passing globals() as locals to exec
changing the code to:

code = R"""
from typing import List
def boo(a: List):
    pass
"""

The problem seems different from Why doesn't an import in an exec in a function work? because the error occurs during the exec execution, not by calling a function/class defined in the code string. Also, doing type annotation of a standalone function works as expected.

Another thing that makes the example work is exec(code, {}). I feel like that's actually the best solution, but I don't see it mentioned on the linked questions, and on the other hand, I haven't really grokked all the details of the problem. @wim could you fill me in? I mean, is it actually a good solution?

BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] if you haven't already, and if you want tips, check out [ask].

Thanks @wjandrea, I'll try that solution.
I don't think this question should be closed, as duplicate. In particular https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505047/why-doesnt-an-import-in-an-exec-in-a-function-work gets an error trying to call the function defined in exec and I sort of understand that the random module wasn't imported in the right scope for the caller. My case result in error during exec, plus type annotating a stand-alone function works as expected.

I think @wim answer is way more explanative than the answers in the linked question.
So I imagine function definitions are treated differently? Do you know where in the python standard these rules are detailed?

Yeah, I think making your comments answer it could be to the benefits of many people who are not so deep into the details of python, thanks!

From the execution model docs section 4.2.2 Resolution of names (emphasis mine):

Class definition blocks and arguments to exec() and eval() are special in the context of name resolution. A class definition is an executable statement that may use and define names. These references follow the normal rules for name resolution with an exception that unbound local variables are looked up in the global namespace.

From the exec docs (emphasis mine):

In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope. If only globals is provided, it must be a dictionary (and not a subclass of dictionary), which will be used for both the global and the local variables.

When exec'ed from within a function scope, the import statement puts List into the local namespace (i.e. the current scope). But the class definition block looks for names in the global namespace, and skips the local namespace. Therefore, you get the error:
NameError: name 'List' is not defined.

A minimal reproducer of the same underlying issue looks like this:
code = """
x = 1
class A:
    x
"""

def f():
    exec(code)

f()  # NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Regarding the changes which make the example work:

Replacing List with list

list is already in the (builtins) namespace.

running exec(code) before foo

This means the import statement puts List into the module (global) namespace, and it's still there when foo is executed.

passing globals() as locals to exec

Now the dict globals() is used for both the global and local variables.

changing the code to ...

You changed it to a function scope. The strange scope behavior is specific to class definition blocks.

Why did you highlight "which will be used for both the global and the local variables"? Isn't the most relevant part of that quote "the code is executed in the current scope"? which means that bindings happen in locals, but List is looked up in globals. BTW, if you add global List to the top of code, the error goes away.

@wjandrea The point there is that if you do do exec(code, d) or exec(code, None, d), it's the same namespace/dict which is used for setting a name (when importing List) and getting a name (lookup of List during the init method definition). It was highlighted to clarify the bullet point 3.
